# News don't show up after TYPO3 reinstall

Tags: typo3, tt-news

After a server crash, I had to re-install TYPO3 using my latest database backup.
While I was at it, I upgraded TYPO3 from whatever I installed about half a year ago to 4.7.2 and, consequently, also had to use a newer tt_news module (3.2.1).

Unfortunately, none of the news sections on my site show up now.  All it says where they should be in the HTML code is:

```
    <!--  CONTENT ELEMENT, uid:24/list [begin] -->
    <div id="c24" class="csc-default">
    <!--  Plugin inserted: [begin] -->

    <!--  Plugin inserted: [end] -->
        </div>
<!--  CONTENT ELEMENT, uid:24/list [end] -->
```

I did update the database when I installed the plugin and clicked the link for the updater script on the plugin's configuration page, although it didn't seem to do anything.

I'm really new to TYPO3, so I can't be sure it's nothing with the HTML template, which I had to reconstruct from scratch.  Also, I'm not really sure yet how you would get an idea of what's going on (or wrong) in cases like this in TYPO3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following:

1. tt_news static template is included or not.
2. Go through the extension manual and check whether the flexform options and typoscript configuration are correct.
3. Make sure that the typoscrpt object browser is error free.
4. Check the error log and set Install tool > All configuration > displayErrors = -1 for your IP address.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, I can't try out your solution any more.  I never really solved the problem, but things are working now: I don't remember exactly what I did, but I think I more or less created the news sections and wrote my news entries from scratch.  I'll accept your answer anyway.